In Matthew 5:13-16, who is the implied subject causing the salt to lose its saltiness? What is the theological implication of 'losing the saltiness?
If" (ἐάν) in v.13, unlike natural salt, which cannot lose its saltiness, suggests that for believers—the "salt of the world"—becoming tasteless is a potential outcome. The verb μωρανθῇ ("becomes tasteless") appears in the Aorist Subjunctive Passive, yet no subject is specified. In contrast, in v.15, "they" actively light the lamp and place it under a basket. Could v.15, in pairing with v.13, provide a clue about who or what causes the salt to lose its saltiness?
Text: Matthew 5:13-16 (NET)

“You are the salt of the earth. But if salt loses its flavor, how can
it be made salty again? It is no longer good for anything except to be
thrown out and trampled on by people. You are the light of the
world. A city located on a hill cannot be hidden. People do not
light a lamp and put it under a basket but on a lampstand, and it
gives light to all in the house. In the same way, let your light
shine before people, so that they can see your good deeds and give
honor to your Father in heaven.


Jesus used motifs from day to day life of Israel to bring home divine truth to them by way of parables and metaphor.
Salt has a number of uses including that of tastemaker.Accordingly, it was prepared from various sources by using different methods. One such use of salt was to preserve the fire in kitchen. In those days, log served as the main fuel of kitchen . Once the supper was cooked, the embers remaining in the stove would go waste unless preserved.One solution was to sprinkle water over it and rekindle it for making breakfast the next day.Another method was to cover the left over ember with salt crystals. The crystals would not get burned out,and would keep the ember live till next morning.Over a period of time, the crystals would lose saltiness and shape. They would then be substituted with fresh salt and discarded on the street.
Similarly, salt used as a preservative say, of  dry fish and dry meat, would also become worthless over a period of time and discarded.
The audience of Jesus was well versed with those practices, and understood  in physical sense,  what Jesus meant by alluding to salt losing saltiness.The spiritual meaning would definitely sink in.
As for the metaphor of light, it came from another practice . Match sticks had not  not been invented, and it was necessary to preserve fire over the night. A small lamp with low flame would serve the purpose.But it ran the risk of getting toppled by pets or mice. Therefore, is was kept under cover , mostly made of clay, with proper ventillation, the flame being hardly visible from outside ( The bushel that Jesus mentioned ( KJV) was meant to measure grain, oil etc upto 36 litres  in one go ).Unlike the salt over the hearth, the flame had no possibility of becoming worthless, but it carried the bane of being self-centred.
Thus, Jesus was presenting two distinct spiritual truths with the metaphors of salt and light.

The passage in Matt 5:13-16 contains two metaphors of Christian experience:

V13 - "You are the salt of the earth."
V14-16 - "You are the light of the world."

The OP asks about the grammatical subjects of the verbs involved in each:
"You are the salt of the earth"
Here is the literal BLB translation:

(S1) You are the salt of the earth, (S2) but if the salt becomes tasteless, with
what will it be salted? (S3) For nothing is it potent any longer except,
having been cast out, to be trampled upon by men.

We have three sentences of quite simple structure
Sentence #1:

"You" refers to those listening to Jesus, ie, the disciples, and more broadly, Christians generally
the verb to be "are" is the coupling verb here
"You" and "salt" are both nominative but only "salt" has the article ("the") and thus, technically, the first sentence should be translated, "The salt of the earth is you"; this makes "the salt" the grammatical subject.  However, the plural noun, "are" prevents this so the above translation remains correct.  In any case, the meaning is clear.

Sentence #2:

Again, "the salt" is the grammatical subject of the verb μωρανθῇ (becomes tasteless).  This salt is a metaphor for the people who are the salt of the earth.
this verb is passive as is the following verb ἁλισθήσεται (will be salted) suggesting that something is making the people non-salty

Sentence #3:

This last sentence is a comment about what happens to non-salty people who are "cast out"

The teaching contained in this verse is precisely parallel to that contained in Heb 6:4-6 -

It is impossible for those

who have once been enlightened,
who have tasted the heavenly gift,
who have shared in the Holy Spirit,
who have tasted the goodness of the word of God
and the powers of the coming age—

and then have fallen away—to be restored to repentance, because they
themselves are crucifying the Son of God all over again and subjecting
Him to open shame.

"You are the light of the world."
Jesus' teaching here is better understood and less controversial and requires no comment.

When Jesus speaks of salt, and the loss of saltiness, this does, indeed, have theological implications. In the mouth of Jesus, the verb 'alizw' occurs three times. Once it is used in the context of sacrifice, and then twice in the context of persons who are redeemed by sacrifice. 'Shall be salted' is always in the future passive form, and it is the aspect of judgment that is key here:

"...but if the salt have lost his savour wherewith shall it be
salted?" Matthew 5:13
"For every one shall be salted with fire and every sacrifice shall be
salted with salt." Mark 9:49 K.J.V.

After Jesus pronounces nine blessings to his disciples, he tells them that they are the salt of the earth. And now I quote to give this explanation from this book:

"Salt is a product of judgment. Brimstone and fire rained down
upon Sodom and Gomorrah and all the plain, but Lot's wife looked back
and was turned into a pillar of salt. Brimstone is a noxious substance which, heated, forms gaseous products that will, if inhaled,
burn the eyes and the nasal ducts - and the lungs within. What is left
after the burning is salt. The Dead Sea, at or very near to the site
of the destruction of those infamous cities, is ten times saltier than
the oceans and its depths are so concentrated that salt -
spontaneously - crystallises out of solution.
Salt stifles vegetative life and bacterial life from growing. For that
very reason, it is a preservative. It keeps things clean. And it gives
a sharpness of flavour to that which is bland. Thus it is
representative of the consequences of judgment. After judgment has
passed over there is cleanness, there is preservation - and there is a
robust flavour.
They upon whom the judgment of God has already passed over in convictions and repentance, are the salt of the earth... These have
been with him who is consuming fire. Thus their saltiness. But if they
lose that proximity and if they lose that saltiness - who then shall
savour them? They are fit for nothing but to be cast out - of the
company of the salted - and to be trodden contemptuously by the men of
this world... Better never to know the way of righteousness than to
end one's life in such a way.
Then at the end of the ninth of Mark... Jesus tells us that every
one shall be salted with fire and every sacrifice shall be salted with
salt. Not every sacrifice was burned with fire... But every
sacrifice was salted with salt. None were without it, Leviticus
2:13.
And every single one shall be salted with fire. Pas means every or
all. It is everyone, none excluded. Everyone shall, one way or
another, pass through fire. And be salted. It is an inevitable feature
of human existence. Because of whom made us ... for also the God of us:
fire consuming. Jehovah Tsidkenu, pp.28-30 Nigel Johnstone, Belmont Publications, 2019. http://www.belmontpublications.co.uk [Bold
emphasis mine]

The answer then, lies in the bold statements already given:
'Shall be salted' is always in the future passive form, and it is the aspect of judgment that is key here.
Salt is a product of judgment.
Salt is representative of the consequences of judgment.
They upon whom the judgment of God has already passed over in convictions and repentance, are the salt of the earth.
Every one shall be salted with fire and every sacrifice shall be salted with salt.

The emphatic 'you—you alone' highlights the unique and irreplaceable role believers play as salt and light in a morally decaying and darkened world. The terms 'earth' for salt and 'world' for light suggest a universal application. 'You are' in the plural, applies to all followers of Christ, not just the apostles or the original Jewish audience, who embody the Beatitudes.
Notably, Jesus uses stable natural elements—salt and light—each inherently constant in its properties. Salt retains its flavor in all circumstances, and light naturally shines without self-restriction. Yet, by choosing these elements, Jesus introduces a striking contrast: while salt naturally retains its flavor, the "saltiness" of believers can be lost.
The Subject Who Causing the Salt to Lose Saltiness
In the context of the Sermon on the Mount, Jesus uses "salt" to signify the believer's role in resisting moral corruption in the world, rather than referring to other ceremonial functions of salt, such as sacrifices, covenants, purification, or flavoring.
While verse 13 does not specify what causes salt to "lose its saltiness," verse 15 provides insight. Jesus implies that this loss can occur through the believer’s own choices, similar to the deliberate act of placing a lit lamp under a basket. This suggests that a believer’s influence can be diminished—or even lost entirely, with no chance of restoration, resulting in being "thrown out and trampled"—through personal actions that compromise their spiritual integrity and, thus, effectiveness in the world.
Furthermore, with "If" (ἐάν) and the Aorist Subjunctive Passive for “losing saltiness,” Jesus indicates a real, though conditional, risk for believers—one of losing their essential quality and effectiveness through neglect or compromise. This serves as both a warning and a reminder, underscoring the critical nature of the calling believers have as "salt" and "light" in the world, as well as the consequences of failing to maintain their "saltiness" and illuminating presence.
The Salt vs. Saltiness
In the context of Matthew 5:13, "salt" represents the believer’s role and identity as an agent of moral preservation and influence in the world. "Saltiness," on the other hand, refers to the essential quality or distinctiveness that enables believers to fulfill this role effectively. While salt signifies a believer's purpose, saltiness is the inner spiritual vitality—rooted in faith, integrity, and holiness—that empowers them to live out that purpose. Losing saltiness thus implies a loss of the distinctive spiritual qualities, a "living faith" encompasses all aspects of a true believer, including being Spirit-filled and empowered by God. This dynamic faith transforms and sustains believers, enabling them not only to live out the gospel but also to be victorious Christian warriors—overcoming challenges, resisting spiritual decay, and boldly standing as "salt and light" in a darkening world.
Causes of the Loss of  'Saltiness'
Among all the teachings of Jesus, His parables—such as The Sower and The True Vine and the Branches—vividly illustrate the importance of not losing "saltiness." The essential point in each is to remain connected to Jesus and to abide in Him, who is the author and perfecter of our faith (Hebrews 12:2). As Jesus said, "Whoever has my commandments and keeps them, he it is who loves me. And he who loves me will be loved by my Father, and I will love him and manifest myself to him" (John 14:21).
(The following list covers key causes that can lead to a loss of "saltiness," though it is not exhaustive. Reader input to these lists is welcome!)

Feeding on the Word of God -"So faith comes from hearing, and hearing through the word of Christ" (Romans 10:17). Believers must remain connected to Jesus, the "bread of life" (John 6:35), as He warns, "If anyone does not abide in me, he is thrown away like a branch and withers" (John 15:6).
Remaining in the Light and Practicing Love - Walking in the light includes practicing love for God and fellow believers. "Whoever keeps His commandments...by this we know that He abides in us, by the Spirit whom He has given us" (1 John 3:24).
Putting on the Armor of God - Paul advises, "Take up the whole armor of God...and the sword of the Spirit, which is the word of God, praying at all times in the Spirit" (Ephesians 6:13, 17-18), to stay spiritually prepared.
Training for Godliness - "Rather, train yourself for godliness...godliness is of value in every way, as it holds promise for the present life and also for the life to come" (1 Timothy 4:7-8).
Maintaining Fellowship through Confession- Keeping fellowship with God requires honesty about our sins: "If we confess our sins, He is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness" (1 John 1:9).

The Parable of the Sower illustrates different causes for a failure to yield a spiritual harvest: the roadside soil symbolizes indifference or loss of interest; the rocky ground represents those who give up during trials; and the thorny ground stands for being choked by the love for worldly things. Each of these represents a choice not to remain in the Word. Similarly, a fruitless branch loses its effectiveness and “saltiness” when it ceases to abide in Christ.
Theological Implications of 'Losing Saltiness'
The concept of "losing saltiness" carries profound theological implications, particularly in light of Jesus' words: "How can it be made salty again? It is no longer good for anything except to be thrown out and trampled on by people." This strong language implies the irreversibility of lost saltiness—of faith itself. The severity of being 'thrown out and trampled' serves as a metaphor for the grave outcome of losing salvation. This echoes passages like Matthew 8:12; 13:42, 50; and 22:13, suggesting that, as serious as it is to never enter the Kingdom, it is even worse to have once possessed faith and then lost it, like Judas Iscariot, for whom Jesus said it would have been better never to have been born.
Challenges to the Doctrine of Perservierence
The potential for losing saltiness challenges doctrines of Election and Predestination, particularly interpretations suggesting that those who fall away were never truly 'elected' or 'predestined' from the start. Jesus’ language suggests that His followers genuinely possess this identity, along with the potential to fulfill or lose it.
Jesus' emphatic language, calling His followers "salt" and "light," affirms that they are genuinely endowed with this identity and purpose. His teachings underscore the believer’s responsibility to maintain faith through obedience and connection to Christ, highlighting the active role of faith and commitment in spiritual vitality.
If believers could not lose their "saltiness," Jesus’ warning would seem redundant. His clear statement, "You are the salt of the earth," confirms that His followers are indeed genuine "salt," capable of influencing the world. Likewise, "You are the light of the world" reinforces that believers are intended to shine visibly and effectively. The risk of losing "saltiness" or dimming as "light" suggests not just a lapse in identity, but a failure in purpose and witness, rendering them akin to the "useless" or "evil servant" in the Parable of the Talents and Minas.
Conclusion:
This discussion on "losing saltiness" highlights the relational and covenantal responsibilities of believers, challenges assumptions of irrevocable eternal security, and underscores the call to a living, enduring faith that remains active and influential in the world. Despite longstanding doctrines such as TULIP, Jesus’ words should settle the debate. He has spoken, and that should end the discussion.
As believers, this insight calls us to a life of intentional connection to Christ, actively embodying His teachings and allowing His Spirit to sustain our "saltiness." Reflecting on our "saltiness" is essential for fulfilling our purpose in the world, motivating us to nurture a faith that stands firm, grows stronger, and shines brightly.
